# yaml-cpp to std::vector iteration weird behaviour

Tags: c++, vector, stdmap, yaml-cpp

I found something (in my opinion) rather weird while reading in a yaml file. Maybe one of you can explain me the difference between the two codes.

The yaml file I'm trying to read looks something like this:

```
map:
  - [0 0 0 0]
    - 0:
      - 0.123
    - 1:
      - -0.234
  - [0 0 0 1]
    - 0:
      - 0.00
    - 1:
      - 1.234
# and many more vector to int to doubles.
```

Now I'm trying to read this into a `std::map<std::vector<int>, std::map<int, double> >`for later use.

I tried to do it using the STL conversion from yaml-cpp:

```
std::map<std::vector<int>, std::map<int, double> > the_map = node.as<std::map<std::vector<int>, std::map<int, double> > >();
```

But since this did not work (don't have the error message right now, but this isn't really what the question is about just as an explanation) I wrote my own read routine like this:

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::LoadFile(name);
for(YAML::const_iterator n = node["map"].begin(); n != node["map"].end(); ++n){
    auto n_0 = (*n).begin();
    for(auto it = n_0->first.as<std::vector<int> >().begin(); it != n_0->first.as<std::vector<int> >().end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    // Some more stuff
}
```

And it results in some weird output:

```
937068720 21864 0 0 
937068720 21864 0 1
```

However if I change it to this code:

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::LoadFile(name);
for(YAML::const_iterator n = node["map"].begin(); n != node["map"].end(); ++n){
    auto n_0 = (*n).begin();
    std::vector<int> vec = n_0->first.as<std::vector<int> >();
    for(auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
    // Some more stuff
}
```

Everything is as expected:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1
```

What is the difference between the two? why do I have to specifically declare the vector?
Even putting brackets around the statement before `.begin()` does not make a difference. Like this:

```
for(auto it = (n_0->first.as<std::vector<int> >()).begin(); it != (n_0->first.as<std::vector<int> >()).end(); ++it)
```

Can somebody explain this to me? What is the difference between the first and the second code?

And since I'm new to YAML I'm happy about any improvement suggestions to reading such a file, this is however **not** my primary concern.

Comment: In the first version, you call `first.as<std::vector<int> >()` twice. Each call returns a different vector, so you are performing UB by comparing an iterator obtained from one vector with an iterator obtained from a different vector. The first version also takes the `begin()` from a temporary vector and continues using it after the temporary vector has destructed, which is another source of UB.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes more sense, but why does it terminate then after exactly the four outputs? shouldn't it run into undefined behavior?

Comment: Terminating after exactly four outputs is a legal manifsetation of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your YAML isn't valid! See, e.g., an [online parser](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/); and `yaml-cpp` agrees: running the utility function`util/parse` with your YAML gives:

```
yaml-cpp: error at line 3, column 5: end of sequence not found
```

Perhaps you meant something like:

```
map:
  [0 0 0 0]:
    - 0:
      - 0.123
    - 1:
      - -0.234
  [0 0 0 1]:
    - 0:
      - 0.00
    - 1:
      - 1.234
```

This, at least, is valid YAML, but it's probably not of the format you're expecting. Here's an analysis:

```
map:           // map of string ->
  [0 0 0 0]:   //  map of vector of int ->
    - 0:       //   vector of map of int to ->
      - 0.123  //    vector of double
    - 1:
      - -0.234
  [0 0 0 1]:
    - 0:
      - 0.00
    - 1:
      - 1.234
```

In standard library functions, this would be a

```
std::map<string, std::map<std::vector<int>, std::vector<std::map<int, std::vector<double>>>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for that! Since the file is written by my own code I changed it to represent the proper structure, so a `map<string, map<int, double> >`. Maybe you could help me out with writing such a structure. I tried the Emitter or force_insert into a Node, but both did not turn out as expected (I get a lot of question marks in the yaml file...). I can open a new question, if that makes it easier :)